# Need to remove unwanted prefix in created header

Tags: apache-2.2, php

I'm trying to generate specific headers to mimic a service provider. However, I keep getting the `HTTP_` prefix added to my headers.

Configuration file:

```
<IfModule headers_module>
    RequestHeader set ntPrincipal "abcdef"
</IfModule>
```

Output in PHP,

`[HTTP_NTPRINCIPAL] => abcdef`

The desired header would need to be:

`[NTPRINCIPAL] => abcdef`

I've tried the following which doesn't work either (I don't see the header at all using this):

```
<IfModule headers_module>
    Header set ntPrincipal "abcdef"
</IfModule>
```

**Update #1**

The service provider/environment I'm trying to mimic is Apache using Shibboleth SP.

**Update #2**

This local copy is running on WAMP on Windows 7. I just did the following and they seem to appear properly:

```
var_dump(getallheaders());
```

Output:

```
'ntPrincipal' => string 'abcdef' (length=6)
```

[The hint was found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15382407/not-all-headers-available-in-server-php).

Having to do this is going to be counter productive for us. My dev/test/production environments work fine having Shibboleth providing these headers properly, I fail to see how I can't specify them in my config file and have them appear as if they were served by Shibboleth.

Comment: I think that PHP in general adds `HTTP_` in front of all headers so that they don't conflict with other variables.  That is, your header is being sent properly; PHP is simply adding the `HTTP_` prefix to the *variable* name.

Comment: @larsks Well, in my other environments (dev, test and prod), I have Apache/Shibboleth configured and they provide headers without the HTTP prefix. In this case, it's a local environment/copy I'm trying to configure and I was wanting to see if I could skip the configuration of Shibboleth by faking the necessary headers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems for PHP, you have to use the following syntax in the configuration file to obtain keys without the `HTTP_` prefix:

```
SetEnv ntPrincipal "abcdef"
```

[Source](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php#97106)